# Insert QR code into PDF using gem receipts in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, qr-code, prawn, receipt

I'm using gem 'receipts' by Chris Oliver, and I want to insert QRcode with payment details (to the footer section for example).
Models: Partner and Charge.
I want QR code to contain model attributes, like these: charge.partner.iban, charge.amount and something like that.
**Charge**.rb has method receipt:

```
  def receipt
    Receipts::Invoice.new(
      details: [
        ["Receipt Number", "123"],
        ["Date paid", Date.today],
        ["Payment method", "ACH super long super long super long super long super long"]
        ],
        company: {
          name: "Example, LLC",
          address: "123 Fake Street\nNew York City, NY 10012",
          email: "support@example.com",
          logo: File.expand_path("./app/assets/images/logo.png")
        },
        recipient: [
          self.partner.name,
          self.partner.address,
          "City, State Zipcode",
          nil,
          "customer@example.org"
        ],
        line_items: [
          ["<b>Item</b>", "<b>Unit Cost</b>", "<b>Quantity</b>", "<b>Amount</b>"],
          ["Subscription", "$19.00", "1", "$19.00"],
          [nil, nil, "Subtotal", "$19.00"],
          [nil, nil, "Tax", "$1.12"],
          [nil, nil, "Total", "$20.12"],
          [nil, nil, "<b>Amount paid</b>", "$20.12"],
          [nil, nil, "Refunded on #{Date.today}", "$5.00"]
        ],
        footer: "Thanks for your business. Please contact us if you have any questions."
      )
  end
```

charges_controller has:

```
  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json
      format.pdf { send_pdf }
    end
  end
```

```
private
    def send_pdf
      send_data @charge.receipt.render,
        filename: "#{@charge.created_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}-gorails-receipt.pdf",
        type: "application/pdf",
        disposition: :inline # or :attachment to download
    end
```

charges/show.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to "View invoice", charge_path(@charge, format: :pdf) %>
```

I tried using prawn-qrcode, but couldn't make it.
Maximum what I get is something as line of text in the footer. [image]
When I put this in receipts method:

```
    qrcode = RQRCode::QRCode.new(self.partner.ico.to_s)
    png = qrcode.as_png(
      resize_gte_to: false,
      resize_exactly_to: false,
      fill: 'white',
      color: 'black',
      size: 120,
      border_modules: 4,
      module_px_size: 6,
      file: nil # path to write
    )
```

and this in the footer:
`footer: ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag(png.to_data_url)`

What should I do to insert QRcode with desired data? Is there any examples of similar task?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note**: This is untested as-is but should work based on the documentation of the libraries themselves.

`receipts` uses `prawn` to generate pdfs.

Someone has created a QR Code renderer for prawn called [`prawn-qrcode`](https://github.com/jabbrwcky/prawn-qrcode) which uses `rqrcode` so you may be able to use this as a simple bridge between the 2 libraries.

Theoretical Example:

```
def send_pdf
  receipt = @charge.receipt
  qr_code = RQRCode::QRCode.new(self.partner.ico.to_s)
  receipt.render_qr_code(qr_code, extent: 72)
  send_data receipt.render,
    filename: "#{@charge.created_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}-gorails-receipt.pdf",
    type: "application/pdf",
    disposition: :inline # or :attachment to download
end
```

Additional Notes:

- You may have to play around with positioning e.g. `render_qr_code(qr_code, pos: [x,y])`
- I am not sure what `self.partner.ico.to_s` generates

Comment: Wow, incredible. `self.partner.ico.to_s` is just random partner's attribute for the test data. Probably I'll need to make an array for IBAN, SWIFT, amount etc.. I've tried to put in QRcode in the model method, but this is so much easer to make it in the controller. Thank you!